# Sharing information between C# project and WiX

Tags: c#, build, wix, dry

I have an application that starts and stops a specific service. However that service is named differently depending on what configuration I build the project in. In my WiX setup I have

```
<ServiceInstall
    <!-- etc... -->
    Name='$(var.ServiceName)'
    DisplayName='$(var.ServiceDisplayName)' />
```

where `var.ServiceName` comes from an include file specified during the build process. I have to use the same service name in my C# code, but my problem with this approach is that the service names are written in two different places. How can I get the service name into one place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider putting the service name into a registry key, where your C# code can easily access it. Since you install a service, your product is not copy-deployable anyway so using the registry could be an option.

Comment: Relevant information from the WiX manual: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/write_a_registry_entry.htm

Answer (score 0):

How is the C# code getting the service name? If it is picking up from config, then you can edit the config during install and get the installer to write the service name in to the config file, that way you keep the code in step with the value you specified in the WiX include.

EDIT.
In response to the question; by edit I mean configure the installer to edit the config for you at install time. I agree that doing it "by hand" (or requesting the user do it) is a bad idea. You can set this up in WiX. You need to use the [XML File custom action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_xmlfile.htm), the WiX would look something like this snippet:

```
<Component ...>
  <UTIL:XmlConfig>
    Id=...
    On="install"
    Action="create"
    File=[.. config file ID goes here ...]
    ElementPath="//myElement/livesHere
    Node="value"
    Name="someNodeName"
    Value="some value to set"
    ...
```

Sorry I can't paste a real snippet, our WiX config is proprietary:( Hopefully that doc link will see you right.

Comment: What's the best way to edit the config file to match the WiX file? Also I would prefer that the configuration is inaccessible to text editors, as it's something that shouldn't change after install. A config file as an embedded resource would work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are naming it based on the configuration, why don't you use the `$(var.ProjectName.Configuration)` (where ProjectName is the name of your C# project) in the name of the service?

Comment: It's a good idea. In my particular case the project configuration names are not good names for a windows service.

Comment: In that case you can just us them to build up the fullname or change them. They are just artibritarily called Debug and Release and can be renamed to whatever you like.

Comment: How do I get my project configuration name into C# code at that point?

Comment: I assume you mean the this.ServiceName in the code itself? Why do you need to keep that in sync?

Comment: The software has to start and stop the service, which means I need the service name to be accessible from C#.